# Time chart labels with some X axis labels using Chart js v3

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to do a humidity and temperature Chart using [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/). My problem is that the time when the temperature and humidity is taken is different between them.

For example: I can have a temperature value measured at 11:01h AM and the humidity at 11:05h.

Also I have more temperature points than humidity points.

So I would like that the x axis would be just time, and fix the time in the point of each dataset, like this I can have differents quantity of point in each dataset and print both datasets in same chart.

I'm trying to use time type for x axis but it doesn't work properly because i have to fix the number of points with the label attribute.

```
            data:{
                labels,
                datasets: [{
                    //label: 'My First dataset',
                    //backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    //borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    //data: sensorValues,
                    data
                }]
            },
```

```
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        type: 'time',
                        display:false,
                        time: {
                            unit: 'minute',
                            displayFormats: {
                                hour: "DD/MM | HH:mm"
                            },

                        },
                    },
                    y: {
                        type: 'linear'
                    }
                }
```

Edit 1:

I changed the data structure, now the structure is:

```
var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('sensorValuesChart'), {
            type: 'line',
            data:{
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'My First dataset',
                    //backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    data: sensorValues,
                    //data
                }]
            },
            options: {
                parsing: {
                    xAxisKey: 'time',
                    yAxisKey: 'value'
                },
            }
        });
```

And sensorValues is: `[{value: "65", time: "2021-05-19 09:13:41"}, {value: "70", time: "2021-05-19 09:09:39"}, ...]` but nothing is showed.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html), the labels property is optional. The easy answer is just not to use it. You can always use the `{x,y}` or `{t,y}` formats, which will build the labels on the fly. Alternately, you just need to make sure that the number of labels matches the size of the larger dataset, whichever that is.

Comment: I tried that but when I represent the data like `[{t:<some time>, y:<some value>}, {t:<some time>, y:<some value>}, ]` it doesn't works, the in the x axis there aren't any label and the point are not in the chart.

Comment: I imagine the scale wasn't showing because you have specified `display:false` on the scale.

Answer (score 1):

As Samuei pointed out if you have multiple datasets of different length the best way to specify is with the object notation as you did in your edit, in case the keys are different you can also specify the parsing keys at dataset level instead of in the options.

The reason why your chart still isnt showing is that since chart.js v3 you will need to use a date adapter for time axis, chart.js currently has 3 date adapters available (https://github.com/chartjs/awesome#adapters) I used the moment one for this example:

```js
var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('sensorValuesChart'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      //backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: [{
        value: "65",
        time: "2021-05-19 09:13:41"
      }, {
        value: "70",
        time: "2021-05-19 09:09:39"
      }],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    parsing: {
      xAxisKey: 'time',
      yAxisKey: 'value'
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        display: true,
        time: {
          unit: 'minute',
          displayFormats: {
            hour: "DD/MM | HH:mm"
          },

        },
      },
      y: {
        type: 'linear'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@0.1.1"></script>

<canvas id="sensorValuesChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hey ! Thank you very much, that works, however, the chart.js version is 2.29, and not 3.X that is the version that i'm using. I guess that my problem may be In the examples that I have seen on internet were old, I am trying to do it just with the official documentation. Thanks.

Comment: You are using the v3 syntax so that might be a reason why it's not working please check the specific v2 docs on how to work with chart.js: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/